# Ruby: How to detect when one side of a socket has been closed

Tags: ruby, sockets

How can I detect that a socket is half-open?  The case I'm dealing with is when the other side of a socket has sent a FIN and the Ruby app has ACKed that FIN.  Is there a way for me to tell that the socket is in this condition?

Take, for example:

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPServer.new('0.0.0.0', 5010)

loop do
  c = s.accept

  until c.closed?
    p c.recv(1024)
  end
end
```

In this case, when I telnet into port 5010, I'll see all my input until I close the telnet session.  At that point, it will print empty strings over and over as fast as it can.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61675/recovering-from-a-broken-tcp-socket-in-ruby-when-in-gets">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61675/recovering-from-a-broken-tcp-socket-in-ruby-when-in-gets</a>, not sure if it helps any tho!

Comment: Haivng the same issue. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I'd read up on socket communication. I'd advice the excellent book by Jesse Storimer: working with tcp sockets. I don't have any stocks or anything, just think it is a really good book on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the blocking call recv, which will return nil when the other end closes. The socket won't be closed until you close it. Change

```
  until c.closed?
    p c.recv(1024)
  end
```

to

```
while (s = c.recv(1024)) && s > 0
   p s
end
c.close
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine `IO#read` and `IO#eof?` to check this.

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new('0.0.0.0', 5010)

loop do
  client = server.accept
  client.read(1024) until client.eof?
  puts 'client closed connection'
  client.close
end
```